# Biblatex: omit author

Tags: biblatex

In the traditional "humanities" writing style it may happen to refer to an author and want to cite his/her works without the author name, perhaps because you are discussing him/her works and adding the name would be redundant. I am not necessary referring to ibidem styles or similar, but to how to introduce bibliographic data whenever the author name is useless or does not fit well in the context. Here is a MWE (not really minimal because I obviously need some citations:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-note]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Annas:HellenisticVersion,
  Title                    = {{T}he {H}ellenistic {V}ersion of {A}ristotle's {E}thics},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Journal                  = {The Monist},
  Pages                    = {80-96},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Volume                   = {73},
}
@Article{Annas:Emotions,
  Title                    = {{E}picurean {E}motions},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Journal                  = {GRBS},
  Pages                    = {145-64},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Volume                   = {30},
}
@Book{Annas:Morality,
  Title                    = {{T}he {M}orality of {H}appiness},
  Location                 = {New York - Oxford},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {1993},
}
@Book{Annas:Intelligent-virtue,
  Title                    = {{I}ntelligent virtue},
  Location                 = {Oxford},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% CITENOAUTHOR
  \newcommand\citenoauthor[1]{%
  {\citetitle{#1}\addspace%
                         \mkbibparens{%
                            \citelist{#1}{location}\addcolon\addspace%
                         \citelist{#1}{publisher}\addcomma\addspace%
                         \citeyear{#1}}%
                                     }%
 }   

%
\begin{document}
\section{Standard}
Annas' well known book of ancient ethics is very important%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:Morality}. I would refer also to another
more recent work, \cite{Annas:Intelligent-virtue}.}%
. Her article on Aristotle and the Hellenistic world is worth mentioning%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:HellenisticVersion}. See also her contribution on
Epicurus: \cite{Annas:Emotions}.}.

\section{New version}
Annas' book is very important%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:Morality}. I would refer also to another
more recent work, \citenoauthor{Annas:Intelligent-virtue}.}%
. Her article on Aristotle is good%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:HellenisticVersion}. See also her contribution on
Epicurus: \citenoauthor{Annas:Emotions}.}.
%
\end{document}
```

I defined a newcommand which I called \citenoauthor. It prints all the fields/lists I need except the author. It works well for books but not for article, for example. I tried do use `\ifentrytype{book}{...}` but I did not succeed. Any possible definition to say "now, and only now, do not print the author field"?

I attach also the output of this example. Note 3 is OK, but note 4, referring to an article, is obviously wrong:

1 Standard

Annas’ well known book of ancient ethics is very important[1]. Her article on
Aristotle and the Hellenistic world is worth mentioning[2].

2 New version

Annas’ well known book of ancient ethics is very important[3]. Her article on
Aristotle and the Hellenistic world is worth mentioning[4].

1 Julia Annas. The Morality of Happiness. New York - Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1993. I would refer also to another more recent work, Julia Annas. Intelligent virtue. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2011.

2 Julia Annas. “The Hellenistic Version of Aristotle’s Ethics”. In: The Monist 73 (1989), pp. 80–96. See also her contribution on Epicurus: Julia Annas. “Epicurean Emotions”. In: GRBS 30 (1989), pp. 145–64.

3 Annas, The Morality of Happiness, see n. 1. I would refer also to another more recent work, Intelligent virtue (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2011).

4 Annas, “The Hellenistic Version of Aristotle’s Ethics”, see n. 2. See also her contribution on Epicurus: “Epicurean Emotions” (location: publisher, 1989).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should set-up a new citation command, based on `\cite` and use it to call bib macros that first clear the `author` (and perhaps more fields) before calling the standard macros.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-note]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Annas:HellenisticVersion,
  Title                    = {{T}he {H}ellenistic {V}ersion of {A}ristotle's {E}thics},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Journal                  = {The Monist},
  Pages                    = {80-96},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Volume                   = {73},
}
@Article{Annas:Emotions,
  Title                    = {{E}picurean {E}motions},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Journal                  = {GRBS},
  Pages                    = {145-64},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Volume                   = {30},
}
@Book{Annas:Morality,
  Title                    = {{T}he {M}orality of {H}appiness},
  Location                 = {New York - Oxford},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {1993},
}
@Book{Annas:Intelligent-virtue,
  Title                    = {{I}ntelligent virtue},
  Location                 = {Oxford},
  Author                   = {Annas, Julia},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% CITENOAUTHOR
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenoauthor}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffootnote
     {\usebibmacro{footcite:noauthor}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:noauthor}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{footcite:noauthor}{%
  \clearname{author}\usebibmacro{footcite}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:noauthor}{%
  \clearname{author}\usebibmacro{cite}}

\begin{document}
\section{New version}
Annas' book is very important%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:Morality}. I would refer also to another
more recent work, \citenoauthor{Annas:Intelligent-virtue}.}%
. Her article on Aristotle is good%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:HellenisticVersion}. See also her contribution on
Epicurus: \citenoauthor{Annas:Emotions}.}.

\section{Standard}
Annas' well known book of ancient ethics is very important%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:Morality}. I would refer also to another
more recent work, \cite{Annas:Intelligent-virtue}.}%
. Her article on Aristotle and the Hellenistic world is worth mentioning%
\footnote{\cite{Annas:HellenisticVersion}. See also her contribution on
Epicurus: \cite{Annas:Emotions}.}.

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\citenoauthor` is above is based on that of `\cite` in `verbose-note.cbx`, the only change is `\usebibmacro{footcite}` has been replaced by `\usebibmacro{footcite:noathor}` and similarly for `\usebibmacro{cite}`.  The `:coauthor` versions of the bibmacros are then defined to clear the `author` field and call the standard macros.  You could make similar variations on the other citation commands in a similar way.

Comment: Your system is perfect, thanks I would like to remark that also the non-standard `philosophy-verbose` style has this feature, but it is based on `verbose-trad2` -- but my publisher requires a style similar to `note` or `inote`.